# Optimize a GridView of data inside a pageview

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a custom calendar package but I'm having some performance difficulties while doing that.

My calendar layout is built from PageViews and each pageview contains a Gridview and each GridView contains 42 children representing the days of the month. Like this:-

[image: GridView Image]

---

**Issue -**

The problem is with scrolling the pageview. When I scroll to the new PageView the new PageView gets build and it builds its GridView and GridView builds its Children. All these tasks while scrolling leads to jank in scrolling animation.

**Note:** Scrolling to previous PageViews is smooth because I'm using AutomaticKeepAlives in PageView which stops PageView from rebuilding constantly on scroll.

---

**DartPad -**

The example DartPad for the above calendar can be found here - https://dartpad.dev/?id=762d835c5b9acadd785ee9269294c1e6

---

Now, what I'm looking for are the ways through which I can improve its performance.

Maybe I can somehow reuse the components for GridView children's dates by manually caching them by storing them as fields somewhere. But I don't know if that would work as these date styles have non-constant properties like the trailing one has different colors and the general one has a different one.

Maybe I can somehow preload pageviews in advance? I don't know if that would work when swiping fast.

Also, if it matters, currently I'm using Riverpod in my package for managing the calendar state.

So, if there is any way to improve the performance then please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Current dirty solutions I found to this problem are:-

- Setting `viewportFraction: 0.99` in PageController of PageView. (It will help as it preloads the previous page and forward page). Suggested here [#504337877](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31191#issuecomment-504337877).
- Or use this [preload_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view) package. Suggested here [#636388237](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31191#issuecomment-636388237).

Currently, flutter doesn't support pre caching the PageView pages in advance but there are several issues about it on Github like this - [#31191](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31191) , [#45632](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45632) , and a closed pull request [#42107](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42107) due to IOS related issue.

I failed to reuse the same widget in multiple places without rebuilding them.

And even if I succeed with the above I might fail to reuse states of child widgets of PageView as changing Pages means the whole child of PageView to be rebuilt as the index is new. So I cannot cache child widgets until I can reuse states in PageView.builder and GridView.Builder. A similar case for ListView is described in [#49126](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49126).

If I'm wrong about the reusing same widget at multiple places then please correct me with a working small example as I'm more than happy to learn more. You can use [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7ba9a0d372913a792a0a7602d6fe255a) as starting point. The task is to bring the rebuild of customContainer from 42 to 1.

Not accepted as an answer as there could be more great answers to this in the future.